# New user account PostgreSQL is created on its own

Tags: macos, postgresql

After downloading [PgAdmin4](https://www.pgadmin.org/) on my MacBook, a new user account "PostgreSQL" was created without my knowledge and with a password that I don't know. Is this normal?

Comment: Simply downloading a file cannot create a new user account.  To do so, you need admin credentials which would require you entering in your password.  There seems to be a lot of steps missing between downloading the app and your discovery of the PostsgreSQL user account.  What exact steps did you take?

Comment: You might want to ask this question at the pgAdmin [Support Mailing List](https://www.pgadmin.org/support/list/).